# How to change dpi for emulator in android in eclipse Juno?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, eclipse-juno

I would like to change screen dpi for emulator in eclipse Juno,I tried to do it as 480 dp but its still reflects only 320 as dpi only.I would like to have dpi as 440.Kindly do help me on this,even this has been answered many times in past it tend to vary with version release of editing dpi value & haven't been answer on current version I hope.Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You do know that dpi and dp (dip) are different?

Comment: @Shoe rat I have tried it many times,am I doing the right way or else I am missing anything in it.